# 2 different $_POST methods with 2 separate array conditions

Tags: javascript, php, mongodb

I have problem with 1 "*&_POST[submit]*" method, while other one is working fine.

I want to create 2 different **$_POST** methods for catching data from **MongoDB** and parse them into **JSON** in a way that one catches dates between `$gte` and `$lte` datapickers and the other one catches data for one particular date. This is the code:

```
<?php 
ini_set('mongo.long_as_object', 1); 
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'test';
$m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->$dbname;
$results;
$rez;
$collection = $db->test; 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
$array = array( 
 'RasID' => $_POST['razberi'],
 'date' => array('$gte' => $_POST['datepickerOD'], '$lte' =>$_POST['datepickerDO'])
);
$results = $collection->find($array); 
}
elseif(isset($_POST['testic'])){
$array = array(
'date' => array($_POST['datepicker'])
);
$results = $collection->find($array);
}
else
{ 
$results = $collection->find()->limit(100);
} 
$rezic = array();
$series = array();
$i=0;
$br=0;
foreach($results as $result){ 
$series[$i]['Temperatura']=$result['Temperatura'];
$series[$i]['Insolacija']=$result['Insolacija'];
$series[$i]['date']=$result['date'];
$series[$i]['RasID']=$result['RasID'];
$i++;
}
foreach($results as $result){ 
$rezic[$br]['Temperatura']=$result['Temperatura'];
$rezic[$br]['Insolacija']=$result['Insolacija'];
$rezic[$br]['date']=$result['date'];
$rezic[$br]['RasID']=$result['RasID'];
$br++;
}
?>`
```

So with the `$_POST['submit']` method I have no problem at all, it catches dates in a defined range, while the other one `$_POST['testic']` can't pick me up all the files which contains that particular day, in fact it catches me all the data defined by the first form. Please help me out with this one. This is the JS code:

```
<script> 
$(function() { 
$( "#datepickerOD" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }); 
$( "#datepickerDO" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }); 
});
</script> 

<script> 
$(function() { 
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }); 
});
</script> 

var chartData = <?php echo json_encode($series); ?> //this one is used for the first submit form

var fibra = <?php echo json_encode($rezic); ?> //this one is used for the second submit form `$_POST['testic']`.
```

How can I separate these arrays and apply them in these 2 **var**'s? Thank you.

Comment: POst the whole javascript code.

Comment: There is a possibility that both of your $_POST gets submitted i.e. **submit** and **testic**, so it always does the submit one since you're using if and elseif. Try using if instead of elseif for testinc. It might work.

Comment: I recently tried **if** insted **elseif** but it still isn't working, it shouldn't be problem with my javascript code because in my mongo db I have five files for each day, it should grab all files that contains for example: `{"date": "2016-02-20", "somethingID": "a1"}` and  `{"date": "2016-02-20", "somethingID": "a2"}` ... `{"date": "2016-02-20", "somethingID": "a5"}` as a date and put them in an array, I don't know what I'm missing, it's the php problem definitely, not javascript .. just guessing...

Comment: for example if I have 2 data files: `{"date": "2016-02-20", "somethingID": "a1"}` and `{"date": "2016-02-20", "somethingID": "a2"}` this $_POST['testic'] should grab both files, am I right?